# call function since product-variants.tpl Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I'm creating a web in Prestashop and my problem is the next:

I has created a new table in db (mysql) called 'tallas' and I have the size's preferences of the users. Now, I need call this table since the page product-variants.tpl because I would like to put cheeked for default the option select by the customer.

I create this function in classes/Product.php

```
public function getTalla($id_customer){

   $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
   SELECT `talla1`
   FROM `tallas`
   WHERE `cliente` = `$id_customer`');            

   return $result;
}
```

ok, I would like to receive for parameters the user id (I don't know how to do that yet) and I would like to receive the value of `talla1` and then I would like put cheeked the option selected by the customer here in the themes/asmart/templates/catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl in the radio.

```
<li class="float-xs-left input-container">
          <label>
            <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
            <span
              {if $group_attribute.html_color_code}class="color" style="background-color: {$group_attribute.html_color_code}" {/if}
              {if $group_attribute.texture}class="color texture" style="background-image: url({$group_attribute.texture})" {/if}
            ><span class="sr-only">{$group_attribute.name}</span></span>
          </label>
        </li>
```

Sincerely I don't know any idea to how to do that, can someone help me?

UPDATE: The problem is solved!

The problem is solved. I do that:

in classes/Product.php

```
public function getTalla(){
       $variable = Context::getContext()->customer->id;
       $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM `tallas` WHERE `cliente` = `$variable`');            

       return $result;
   }
```

in ProductController.php

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('images_ex',$this->product->getTalla());
```

in product-variants.tpl

```
{if $images_ex[0]['talla1'] == $group_attribute.name} checked="checked"{/if}
```

I hope this can help someone in the future.